# PHP Array, adding to MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Im using the following

```
<?php
$vipInfo = $_POST['vipInfo'];
echo "<pre>";
print_r($vipInfo);
echo "</pre>";

$result = sizeof($vipInfo,0);

  foreach($vipInfo as $key => $value){
    echo "Form ID: $key, Event: $value <br />";


?><!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Form</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript"> 

    var nFloor = "";    

    function removeField(nField){

    nField.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(nField.parentNode);
}

function insertField(){

    var newFieldContainer = document.createElement('div');
    var newFieldLabel = document.createElement('label');
    newFieldLabel.innerHTML = "Event:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";       
    var newField = document.createElement('input');
    newField.type = "text";
    newField.name = "vipInfo[]";
    newFieldContainer.appendChild(newFieldLabel);
    newFieldLabel.appendChild(newField);
    var deleteBtn = document.createElement('input');
    deleteBtn.type = "button";
    deleteBtn.value = "Remove";
    deleteBtn.style.marginLeft = "5px";
    deleteBtn.onclick = function(){removeField(this)};
    newFieldContainer.appendChild(deleteBtn);
    document.forms[0].insertBefore(newFieldContainer,nFloor);
}

function init(){

    var insertBtn = document.getElementById('newFieldBtn')
    insertBtn.onclick = function()
        {
         insertField();
        }
    nFloor = insertBtn;     
}

navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer" ? attachEvent('onload', init, false) : addEventListener('load', init, false);    

</script>
</head>
    <body>
        <form action="process.php" method="post">

            <div class="field"><label>Event:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="vipInfo[]"></label></div>

        <input type="button" id="newFieldBtn" value="New Field"> 
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

    </form>
</body>
```

which gives me a nice little array as so:

```
Array
(
    [0] => test1
    [1] => test2
    [2] => test3

)
Form ID: 0, Event: test1 
Form ID: 1, Event: test2 
Form ID: 2, Event: test3
```

How does on set the script up to enter into a database.
Say i wanted it to enter a joined 'reference number' and then in another field all the test,test2,test3 etc

so
       id   |   field

```
   --------------
   1    |  test

   1    |  test2

   1    |  test3
```

and so on?

Thanks again

D

Comment: First - read the following -> http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php have a go at some coding then come back and ask a more specific question

Answer (score -1):

Try to use [foreach](http://nl2.php.net/foreach) in this case:

```
<?php
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (id, event) VALUES ";
foreach($array AS $id => $event) {
  $sql .= " ('".$id."','".$event."'),";
}
$sql = substr($sql,-1); //Remove the last ,

mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: If the OP had included some basic knowledge of MySQL coding within PHP perhaps this would have been a good answer - but i very much suspect the OP wouldnt know what to put before the 2nd line !!!!

Comment: i blame it on dyslexia im afraid

Comment: @DavidSpalton you blame what on dyslexia ? you managed to write all of the code in your question .... why does it prevent you from doing some research ?

Comment: for forgetting what to look for and for getting in a loop being confused.